# How do I use Codeship CI for a ruby project of mine that uses TK?

Tags: ruby, continuous-integration, tk-toolkit, codeship

I have a ruby project that builds perfectly fine on my machine, but I would like to use CI for the project because I am not the only contributor and it is just a good safeguard. I am using codeship and cannot get the project to build because I need to use `tk` in my project. As `tk` is not itself a gem, how can I get codeship to install `tk` so I can test my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the `tk8.6` and the `tk8.6-dev` packages are installed on the Codeship build VMs.

```
$ dpkg -l tk*
ii  tk                                 8.6.0+6ubuntu3         amd64                  Toolkit for Tcl and X11 (default version) - windowing shell
ii  tk8.5                              8.5.15-2ubuntu3        amd64                  Tk toolkit for Tcl and X11, v8.5 - windowing shell
ii  tk8.6                              8.6.1-3ubuntu2         amd64                  Tk toolkit for Tcl and X11 v8.6 - windowing shell
ii  tk8.6-dev:amd64                    8.6.1-3ubuntu2         amd64                  Tk toolkit for Tcl and X11 v8.6 - development files
```

(You can take a look at installed packages yourself by running a [SSH Debug Build](https://codeship.com/documentation/continuous-integration/ssh-access/) and then using either `dpkg` or a similar tool to query the package index.